# Oracle clob field val

Tags: oracle, clob

I have an issue getting a specific value of clob field.

(I can't create functions) this would be easy.

So assuming a clob field:

key1+val1;key2+val2;key3+val3;key4+val4

Here I wanted to get the value of key3 for instance

I tried to archieve it with dbms_lob.substr & dbms_lob.instr with no success.

Can one maybe help me here?

The order of the values cane be different (key2+val2;key1+val1;key4+val4;key3+val3)

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Regexp_* functions work with clob the same way as with varchar2.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing data like that. Read up on normalization.

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp_replace(clob_column, '^(.*?;)*key3\+([^;]*).*$', '\2')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ea97/1)